# Unable to install ntfs-fuse on RHEL 5.2, missing dependency error

Tags: linux, storage, admin, ntfs, rhel5

I have a rhel 5.2 machine and I am trying to mount a ntfs file system harddisk. I know that we need ntfs and fuse rpms to mount it. By installing those rpms I mounted it in my rhel 5.4 machine. But in 5.2 I followed the same steps but failed to mount. Then after googling I found that 5.2 kernel doesn't support or have fuse kernel by default and then I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145209/mounting-ntfs-filesystem-on-centos-5-2).

Below is the output after doing the steps said in this link.

```
[root@racdb1 ~]# wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.                                                                                        3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
--14:14:20--  http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el                                                                                        5.rf.i386.rpm
Resolving packages.sw.be... 78.46.17.228
Connecting to packages.sw.be|78.46.17.228|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el                                                                                        5.rf.i386.rpm [following]
--14:14:32--  http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-                                                                                        1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
Resolving pkgs.repoforge.org... 78.46.17.228
Connecting to pkgs.repoforge.org|78.46.17.228|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://rpmforge.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-releas                                                                                        e-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm [following]
--14:14:39--  http://rpmforge.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-re                                                                                        lease-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
Resolving rpmforge.sw.be... 78.46.17.228
Connecting to rpmforge.sw.be|78.46.17.228|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://tree.repoforge.org/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-re                                                                                        lease-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm [following]
--14:14:51--  http://tree.repoforge.org/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforg                                                                                        e-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
Resolving tree.repoforge.org... 78.46.17.228
Connecting to tree.repoforge.org|78.46.17.228|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3                                                                                        .6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm [following]
--14:14:59--  http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release                                                                                        -0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
Resolving apt.sw.be... 193.1.193.67
Connecting to apt.sw.be|193.1.193.67|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 16698 (16K) [application/x-redhat-package-manager]
Saving to: `rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm'

100%[=======================================>] 16,698      14.4K/s   in 1.1s

14:15:09 (14.4 KB/s) - `rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm' saved [16698/1                                                                                        6698]

[root@racdb1 ~]# rpm -Uhv rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
warning: rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKE                                                                                        Y, key ID 6b8d79e6
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:rpmforge-release       ########################################### [100%]
[root@racdb1 ~]# yum install fuse fuse-ntfs-3g dkms dkms-fuse
Loading "security" plugin
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
rpmforge                  100% |=========================| 1.9 kB    00:00
primary.sqlite.bz2        100% |=========================| 7.3 MB    01:20
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package fuse available.
No package dkms-fuse available.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fuse-ntfs-3g.i386 0:2013.1.13-2.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: fuse >= 2.6.3 for package: fuse-ntfs-3g
---> Package dkms.noarch 0:2.1.1.2-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
**Error: Missing Dependency: fuse >= 2.6.3 is needed by package fuse-ntfs-3g**
```

I don't know what to do from the above error which I got. I searched in google but I didn't get the solution anywhere. How to solve the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the process to use ntfs file system in rhel 5.2.  I followed the link.

http://oliphauntz.blogspot.in/2011/03/fix-how-to-mount-ntfs-filesystem-on.html#comment-form

In the above link the step " wget http://pbxinaflash.net/source/pogoplug/fuse-2.6.0.tar.gz" is not working. So I manually downloaded fuse-2.6.0 from internet and then installed and configured it. Try the same if anyone is facing the same problem which I faced.